# BottomSheetDialog endless nested scrolling Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, bottom-sheet, android-nestedscrollview, bottomsheetdialogfragment

I have BottomSheetDialog with recyclerView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/dialog_bottom_sheet_padding">

    <..../>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        ..... />
</LinearLayout>
```

Preview:
[image]

What i have:
When recyclerView content is slightly scrolled down, I start swiping up to the content beginning and then the scrolling stops (RecyclerView overscroll effect is visible). How can i do endless scroll?

What i want:
When the very first element is displayed, the scrolling does not stop, but the dialog itself begins to scroll and closes